# Jmeter maven plugin : To specify thread count, loop, ramp up time in Maven

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

In the pom.xml file, I set the following variables and running the JMeter script from maven using the following command. But it doesn't work. This means the thread is not running with 10 users. Can you please help me with this?
Also, in JMeter do I need to set anything?

Maven Command:

`mvn -DJmeterTestFile=ER_SampleTest -DRampUp=2 -DLoopcount=1 -DThreadcount=10 verify`

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmeter-demo</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>jmeter-demo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
      <version>9.1.1.v20140108</version>
      <classifier>hybrid</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
      <artifactId>ApacheJMeter</artifactId>
      <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
      <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
      <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
      <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
      <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>


  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-jar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                 <!-- This configuraition is to specify jmeter script, number  -->
                      <testFilesIncluded>
                             <jMeterTestFile>${JmeterTestFile}.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                     </testFilesIncluded>
                     <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                     <propertiesUser>
                        <Threadcount>${Threadcount}</Threadcount>
                        <Loopcount>${Loopcount}</Loopcount>
                        <Rampup>${RampUp}</Rampup>
                     </propertiesUser>

                          <testPlanLibraries>
                             <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.15.2</artifact>
                 <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.15.2</artifact>
                 <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.15.2</artifact>
                </testPlanLibraries>
                       <excludedArtifacts>
                             <exclusion>commons-pool2:commons-pool2</exclusion>
                             <exclusion>commons-math3:commons-math3</exclusion>
                             <exclusion>org.slf4j:slf4j-nop</exclusion>
                             <exclusion>logkit:logkit</exclusion>
                             <exclusion>avalon-logkit:avalon-logkit</exclusion>
                             <exclusion>jdom:jdom</exclusion>
                             <exclusion>log4j:log4j</exclusion>
                             <exclusion>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclusion>
                             <exclusion>excalibur-logger:excalibur-logger</exclusion>
                        </excludedArtifacts>
             <jmeterExtensions>
                            <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.4</artifact>
                        </jmeterExtensions>

                        <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>

                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/JMeter/plugins/functional/controler/**/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/JMeter/plugins/controler/websocketapp/**</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                        <junitLibraries>
                            <artifact>com.lazerycode.junit:junit-test:1.0.0</artifact>
                        </junitLibraries>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>



    </plugins>
</build>
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending JMeter properties `-DRampUp=2 -DLoopcount=1 -DThreadcount=10` to your jmx file,

So you must use them in your Thread Group:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to define your properties like `JmeterTestFile`, `Threadcount`, etc. in `<properties>` section like:

   ```
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <JmeterTestFile>test</JmeterTestFile>
       <Threadcount>10</Threadcount>
       <Loopcount>5</Loopcount>
       <RampUp>1</RampUp>
   </properties>
   ```
2. You need to move `<configuration>` section from `maven-jar-plugin` to `jmeter-maven-plugin`
3. In your test plan refer the properties using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(Threadcount,)}`.
4. Update your "jmeter*" dependencies to [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) as [JMeter Maven Plugin 2.7.0 is integrated with JMeter 4.0](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin#jmeter-maven-plugin)

Example *pom.xml* file (you might still need to amend it as I don't have idea what else it should be doing apart from running JMeter tests)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jmeter-demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.1.v20140108</version>
            <classifier>hybrid</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- This configuraition is to specify jmeter script, number  -->
                    <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jMeterTestFile>${JmeterTestFile}.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                    </testFilesIncluded>
                    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <Threadcount>${Threadcount}</Threadcount>
                        <Loopcount>${Loopcount}</Loopcount>
                        <Rampup>${RampUp}</Rampup>
                    </propertiesUser>

                    <testPlanLibraries>
                        <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.15.2</artifact>
                        <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.15.2</artifact>
                        <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.15.2</artifact>
                    </testPlanLibraries>
                    <excludedArtifacts>
                        <exclusion>commons-pool2:commons-pool2</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>commons-math3:commons-math3</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>org.slf4j:slf4j-nop</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>logkit:logkit</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>avalon-logkit:avalon-logkit</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>jdom:jdom</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>log4j:log4j</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>excalibur-logger:excalibur-logger</exclusion>
                    </excludedArtifacts>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.4</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>

                    <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
                    <junitLibraries>
                        <artifact>com.lazerycode.junit:junit-test:1.0.0</artifact>
                    </junitLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <JmeterTestFile>test</JmeterTestFile>
            <Threadcount>10</Threadcount>
            <Loopcount>5</Loopcount>
            <RampUp>1</RampUp>
        </properties>

</project>
```